# PLS-00049 bad bind variable While using :OLD

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

```
create or replace trigger dis_sal_his
after delete or insert or update on employee
for each row
declare
  username varchar2(10);
begin
  select user into username from dual;

  insert into employeehistory
  values(:old.id,:old.name,:old.age,:old.address,:old.salary,:old.deletedate);
end;
/
```

After executing
The error message is displayed as:

> 5/89 PLS-00049 bad bind variable 'old.deletedate'

Comment: It looks like there is no `deletedate` in `employee`. You should not insert relying on column order by the way. Make this explicit:  `insert into employeehistory ( <column names here> ) values (:old.id,:old.name,:old.age,:old.address,:old.salary,:old.deletedate);`.

Comment: btw, using `username varchar2(50):=user;` is enough to use instead of the current select statement.

Comment: This is the table. 
                            
  create table employeehistory
(
 id int,
 name varchar2(20),
 age int,
 address varchar2(20),
 salary int,
 deletedate date
);

Comment: @RaghuC edit your question with the additional details. You’ve shared DDL for `employeehistory` in the comments but your trigger is failing to compile because it references the`deletedate` column of the inserted/updated/deleted `employee` row - this is the table that doesn’t have the column. Presumably you want to add logic to the trigger to see if it is a delete and then to use `sysdate`

Answer (score 0):

You can save it in a local variable (like: v_deletedate) and then use that variable in your insert command.

create or replace trigger dis_sal_his

after delete or insert or update on employee

for each row

declare

username varchar2(10);

v_deletedate date;

begin

select user into username from dual;

v_deletedate := :old.deletedate;

insert into employeehistory

values(:old.id,:old.name,:old.age,:old.address,:old.salary,v_deletedate);

end;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).